# convert keras input to numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
Tensor("flatten_3/Identity:0", shape=(None, 100), dtype=float32)
```

Hi I have tried to print tensor as numpy array as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input

print(tf.executing_eagerly())
x = Input(shape=(32,))
print(x.numpy())
```

Comment: Check if `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns True. If not, you'll need to enable it.

Comment: its true default in tf 2.2 AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: That's right but it is possible you disabled it at some point prior (perhaps to execute graphs) and then just forgot to re-enable later? ^^

Comment: it prints true i added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I'm sure there is a cleaner way to visualize your input tensor, but here's a hacky one for what it's worth:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def tf_print(x):
  tf.print("my tensor:")
  tf.print(x)
  return x

iput = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
printt = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf_print)(iput) # branch that prints your tensor
oput = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(iput) # branch that is the rest of your model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[iput], outputs=[oput, printt])
model(4)
```

Comment: i just need to print input only and numpy array

Comment: this prints the input when you run the model.

Comment: as numpy array? and without running anymodel

Comment: nope you can't do that. What do you think would be printed? Something like `[0,0,...,0]`? Because `tf.keras.layers.Input` does not have any data in it, there's nothing in it. It's similar to the old `tf.placeholder`, there's no data in your tensor, so nothing to convert to a `numpy` array. You have to feed it something so it can print it.

Comment: yes i expect like that, , so then thats reason it returns numpy error?